# How to pass a div ID to a PHP function using jQuery AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

PHP Post doesn't receive jQuery ajax post value

I have created an ajax POST with jQuery to obtain the ID of a div and pass it to a PHP function. The function of php is in a folder phpFunction taht contains the file phpFunc.php in the same root of index.php. The post request is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.openModal').click(function() {
                var divId = $(this).attr('id');
                // Invia l'ID al server tramite richiesta AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/icollegati/phpFunction/phpFunc.php',
                    data: {divId: divId},
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Gestisci la risposta del server
                        console.log("Risposta",response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

the PHP function is:

```
function FetchIdNumber(){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Verifica se il parametro "divId" è stato inviato tramite POST
    if (isset($_POST['divId'])) {
        $id = $_POST['divId'];
        echo "ID: " . $id;
        return $id;
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks in adavance for the help.

Comment: Are you sure the modal has an id? Does it work if you put a value manually?

Comment: Yes i checked also if the id is assigned to divId with a console.log

Comment: I would say you receive a JSON and no formdata.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I don't receive form data, only I want get the id of div to pass to php server for a request to db

Comment: How do you call `FetchIdNumber()`? Did you check your browser's DevConsole to validate what gets sent and received?

Comment: But you are using the `$_POST` superglobal to access a formdata. Do a `var_dump()` of `$_POST` and look at `file_get_contents(filename: 'php://input')`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to call the `FetchIdNumber` function in your PHP code.

```php
function FetchIdNumber(){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        // Verifica se il parametro "divId" è stato inviato tramite POST
        if (isset($_POST['divId'])) {
            $id = $_POST['divId'];
            echo "ID: " . $id;
            return $id;
        }
    }
}

// Call the function
FetchIdNumber();
```

Make sure to place the function call `FetchIdNumber();` after the function definition.

Additionally, please ensure that the path to your PHP file is correct. In your AJAX code, you have specified the URL as `http://localhost/icollegati/phpFunction/phpFunc.php`. Make sure that this path is accurate and matches the actual location of the PHP file on your server.